# Appending a value to a key in Python?

Tags: python, append, shelve, pickle

```
if savescores == "y":
        name = raw_input("Enter your name.")
        datfile = filename[0:-4] + ".dat"
        highscores = shelve.open(datfile)
        try:
            highscores[name].append(score)
        except:
            highscores[name] = [score]
```

If this specific player already has a score, I want to append the new score to the scores he already has, but apparently this doesn't work, because it doesn't change his score at all.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what isn't working?  What you have looks OK at first glance (although I would do `except KeyError` instead of a bare `except`).

Comment: It's the "try: highscores[name].append(score)". When I ask it to print the specific player's scores, nothing has changed, it is only the score that I got before, when it should instead have the old scores AND the new scores in sort of a list.

Comment: @Shashank: You mean `setdefault` rather than `get`.  `get` does not mutate the dictionary, `setdefault` does.  See the results of `d = {};d.get('x', []).append(1);print(d)`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yup my bad. `highscores.setdefault('name', []).append(score)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Shelf` object does not detect changes to mutable objects in your shelf.  It only detects assignment.

To fix this, open your shelf with `writeback=True` and make sure to `close` when you are done.  (You can also `sync` every so often to lower memory usage of the cache.)

Relevant docs from [`shelve.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#shelve.open):

> Because of Python semantics, a shelf cannot know when a mutable
>   persistent-dictionary entry is modified. *By default modified objects
>   are written only **when assigned** to the shelf* (see Example). If the
>   optional `writeback` parameter is set to `True`, all entries accessed are
>   also cached in memory, and written back on `sync()` and `close()`; this
>   can make it handier to mutate mutable entries in the persistent
>   dictionary, but, if many entries are accessed, it can consume vast
>   amounts of memory for the cache, and it can make the close operation
>   very slow since all accessed entries are written back (there is no way
>   to determine which accessed entries are mutable, nor which ones were
>   actually mutated).

Note that you can skip opening with `writeback=True` to save memory, but your code will be more verbose as shown in this [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#example) from the `shelve` docs.

```
# as d was opened WITHOUT writeback=True, beware:
d['xx'] = [0, 1, 2]    # this works as expected, but...
d['xx'].append(3)      # *this doesn't!* -- d['xx'] is STILL [0, 1, 2]!

# having opened d without writeback=True, you need to code carefully:
temp = d['xx']      # extracts the copy
temp.append(5)      # mutates the copy
d['xx'] = temp      # stores the copy right back, to persist it

# or, d=shelve.open(filename,writeback=True) would let you just code
# d['xx'].append(5) and have it work as expected, BUT it would also
# consume more memory and make the d.close() operation slower.

d.close()       # close it
```

By the way, this code

```
try:
    highscores[name].append(score)
except:
    highscores[name] = [score]
```

is more concisely expressed as

```
highscores.setdefault(name, []).append(score)
```